# Call taking multiple seconds

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I have an api call in my sagas like this:

`const response = yield call(api.route, accessToken, args, moreArgs)`
and surround it I have a `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`

I also have console.times surrounding the `api.route` call.

The `api.route` call is taking ~3ms

The `yield call(..)` is taking 3000-11000ms

How can I debug this? I'm logging any actions sent to the saga middleware and nothing is running after the initial call. I'd like to find out how I can break into the `call` function and see what's taking so long.